# Dynamic floating content, getting div to float above another div

Tags: css, html, height

http://jsfiddle.net/V7BJM/

The text in the box is going to be dynamic depending on who is logged in. When the blue box has a lot of content like in the jsfiddle, I would like the yellow box to float up under the green. Is this possible or do I need to use some sort of column system, which I know I could use to solve my problem but it would be nice to do it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the best option is to separate the content into two columns, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/V7BJM/1/